# weblogic.deployment.PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.getSharedCacheMode()Ljavax/persistence/SharedCaheMode

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, weblogic, weblogic-10.x

I am getting the following exception on server when deployment my app In Weblogic 10.3.6. Any ideas?

```
weblogic.management.DeploymentException: 
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.throwAppException(BaseDeployment.java:82)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.prepare(BaseDeployment.java:193)
    at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.prepare(EarDeployment.java:59)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.prepare(DeploymentStateChecker.java:154)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.prepare(AppContainerInvoker.java:60)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: weblogic.deployment.PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.getSharedCacheMode()Ljavax/persistence/SharedCacheMode;
    at org.hibernate.ejb.util.LogHelper.logPersistenceUnitInfo(LogHelper.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:526)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:73)
    at weblogic.deployment.BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.initializeEntityManagerFactory(BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:393)
    at weblogic.deployment.BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.initializeEntityManagerFactory(BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:386)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
```

using spring 3.1.2.RELEASE and hibernate jpa 4.1.7.Final and maven

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you add the following dependency to your project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

The `AbstractMethodError` usually indicates a class loading issue, like that when your code is built against JPA 2.0 but at runtime, you only have the JPA 1.0 jar available.

Comment: i added it but the same exception